# Pages: Use different font style for text on the same line

Tags: pages

I noticed that the font style of Pages applies to the entire line by default. Is there a way to use a different style on selected text anywhere on a line?

Comment: you should probably watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zf_up8NE8R8